Calculating radial geometry of mind map
I'm trying to space linked nodes in such a way that they don't overlap. The algorithm for generating the positions is as follows:
const span = 180 * Math.PI/180;

function genPositionsRecursive(node, depth=0) {
     if (node.children) {
        const radius = 1;
        const slice = depth === 0 ? 2 * Math.PI / node.children.length : span / (node.children.length  + 1)
        for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            const child = node.children[i]
            const angle = depth === 0 ? slice * i : (node.angle) + slice*(i+1) - (span/2)
            child.angle = angle;
            child.x = node.x + (radius * Math.cos(angle));
            child.y = node.y + (radius * Math.sin(angle));

            genPositionsRecursive(child, depth+1)
        }
    }
}

The problem is that they can overlap.
I'm interested in adjusting the radius (and possibly the span) of each node to prevent the nodes from overlapping.
Stopping relatively close neighbours from overlapping is more straightforward. It's possible to calculate the overlap using circles or triangles, and make the adjustments based on that.
But much more difficult are scenarios where more distant neighbours overlap, such as this:

What makes the problem in the image especially difficult is that the nodes coming from the orange branch don't overlap on their leftmost/rightmost branches.
It would be fairly straightforward to recursively calculate triangles (using the leftmost/rightmost nodes), coming from the outermost branch, moving in, making the adjustments as you go. But doing that with the above problem would yield triangles that are too big, leaving too much space between branches.
So I'd like some advice on how to calculate the position of the nodes so they don't overlap.
Edit
I've included a code sandbox so you can see the problem and tinker with it.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/three-js-forked-jskkct

I think your solution is almost correct and it makes sense to treat such overlaps as exceptions from the otherwise generally correct algorithm, that is, whenever a new segment is added, check whether this segment overlaps with previously added segments. If you have a set for the already existent segments, you can loop the segments and see whether they overlap with the new one.
Possible equation for a line:

x = a (horizontal)
y = b (vertical)
y = cx + d (anything else)

Now, all your old segments are on such a line, having the first equation, that is, E1 and your new segment is on a line defined by E2. So, you need to find out which (x, y) value(s) complies both to E1 and E2 and then check whether the meeting point(s) of the lines are inside the segments.
A segment:

x = a (horizontal), a1 <= y <= a2
y = b (vertical), b1 <= x <= b2
y = cx + d (anything else) x1 <= x <= x2; y1 <= y <= y2

So, after solving the line equations, apply the segment constraints and see whether the result is empty set. If so, the new segment does not overlap with the old one, otherwise they overlap and you need to adjust at least one of them. Adjustment could be a repeated rotation until there is no overlap.
If you cannot resolve it by rotating, then you need to rotate the parent of the segment as well and so forth. But maybe this will not be necessary.
